# Regex in Python that can extract paths which could contain dots anywhere except end

Tags: python, regex, string, data-processing

I'm processing some raw texts that may contains several links within it. The example links that may appear in the text look like this:

> \\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name
> \\remote_node\shared_path\520.38-nonprod\utli\file_name

Links like above can appear any where in the text, at beginning, in the middle or in the end. Notice that the dots can appear in any chunk of the link but not the last char. For example:

> "Here is an example text and we want to use regex to extract the links. The links we are interested in are \\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name and \\remote_node\shared_path\520.38-nonprod\util\file_name. This text can be continued with even more sentences ..."

By using `re.findall()`, I'm hoping to get a list, ["\\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name", "\\remote_node\shared_path\520.38-nonprod\util\file_name"]

Notice that the dot following the link is not included in the second link as it's the period of the sentence.
We don't know how may chunks/directories consist of a link (>=2 for sure). We only know that the first chunk allows alphanumerical, dots and underscore. The rest of chunks allow alphanumerical, dots, underscore and hyphens, and the link cannot be ended with a dot.

The regex I have currently is:

```
first_chunk= r"\w\."
rest_chunk= r"\w\.\-\\"
pattern = re.compile(r"\\\\[%s]+\\[%s]+" % (first_chunk, rest_chunk))
```

However, this pattern also add ended dots (if any) to the links. After seeing [end-of-line](https://blog.finxter.com/python-regex-start-of-line-and-end-of-line/#:%7E:text=Python%20Re%20End%20of%20String%20(%24)%20Regex,-Similarly%2C%20you%20can&text=The%20findall()%20method%20finds,the%20end%20of%20the%20string.), I also tried

```
first_chunk= r"\w\."
rest_chunk= r"\w\.\-\\"
pattern = re.compile(r"\\\\[%s]+\\[%s]+[^\.]$" % (first_chunk, rest_chunk))
```

or

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\\\\[%s]+\\[%s]+[^\.]$" % (first_chunk, rest_chunk), flags=re.MULTILINE )
```

Neither of the regex can preciously extract the correct links from the text.
I'm wondering how to modify the regex to achieve my goal. Any comments would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use *re* for this? It would be very straightforward to parse the input file without it

Answer (score 1):

You could write the final pattern matching as least 2 times `/` and in the final part of the pattern omit matching the dot.

```
\\\\[\w.]+(?:\\[\w.-]+)+\\[\w-]+(?:\.[\w+-]+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `\\\\` Match `\\`
- `[\w.]+` Match 1+ times either `\w` or `-`
- `(?:\\[\w.-]+)+` Repeat 1+ times starting with `\` and the same character class as before
- `\\[\w-]+` Match `\` again (to have at least 2 occurrences of `\`)  and match 1+ times either `\w` or `-`
- `(?:\.[\w+-]+)*` Optionally repeat `.` and 1+ word chars or `-`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oxjPg3/1).

Example

```
import re

s = r"""Here is an example text and we want to use regex to extract the links. 
The links we are interested in are \\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name and \\remote_node\shared_path\520.38-nonprod\util\file_name. 
This text can be continued with even more sentences ...
\\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name.png"""

pattern = r"\\\\[\w.]+(?:\\[\w.-]+)+\\[\w-]+(?:\.[\w+-]+)*"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[
'\\\\1.123.42.5\\foo\\bar\\file_name', 
'\\\\remote_node\\shared_path\\520.38-nonprod\\util\\file_name', 
'\\\\1.123.42.5\\foo\\bar\\file_name.png'
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It's enlightening. However, this regex missed a corner case as periods in the last chunk but not the last char. For example we want to keep the entire link like this "\\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name.png"

Answer (score 0):

As @Stuart said in the comments, maybe `re` module is unnecessary here:

```py
s = r"""Here is an example text and we want to use regex to extract the links. 
The links we are interested in are \\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name and \\remote_node\shared_path\520.38-nonprod\util\file_name. 
This text can be continued with even more sentences ..."""

for word in s.split():
    if word.startswith("\\"):
        print(word.strip("."))
```

Prints:

```
\\1.123.42.5\foo\bar\file_name
\\remote_node\shared_path\520.38-nonprod\util\file_name
```

Comment: This could be one of the solution! I'll run more cases through this logic and see if any corner case is missing! Thanks!